# Uniqueness of solution to system of integral equations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Given the following system of integral equations for an integrable function $f(x)$:

For all integers $k \ge 1$ holds

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} [f(x)]^k e^{(ikx)} dx = 0$.

If $f(x)$ is real-valued and non-negative, is $f(x)=const$  almost everywhere the only solution to the system? 
Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: For complex-valued functions certainly not: take $f(x)=e^{2ix}$. Is your $f$ real-valued?

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution that comes to mind : $f(x) = \cos(x)$, because then $[f(2\pi-x)]^k \sin(k(2\pi-x)) =[\cos(2\pi-x)]^k \sin(2k\pi-kx) = [\cos(x)]^k [-sin(kx)] = -[f(x)]^k\sin(kx)$ and thus $\int_0^{\pi}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} = 0$.

Any similarly symmetric function would work, e.g. one that is positive like $f(x) = |\pi-x|$.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to search for solutions were f is real valued and non negative.

Comment: Any similarly symmetric function would work, e.g. one that is positive like $f(x) = |\pi-x|$.

Comment: How would be the situation if the functions sin(kx) are replaced by exp(ikx)? Still f is supposed to be real-valued and non-negative. Thanks a lot!